# GoogleAuthIOException : trying sample code of google drive api

Tags: android

I am trying sample code give in 
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

But i am getting "GoogleAuthIOException" on executing

**File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();**

line from code.Can anybody help me out.
I am following all the instructions given in above link

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain the API key from google before using its APIs

Comment: Thanks friend. But i have already registered my app in cloud console and i got an API key under registered app section. Are you referring to same API key?

Comment: Yes friend i have uninstalled my applications many times and tried to execute same code. Is there any other possibility of error?

Comment: it seems that there is an issue with your Authorization

Comment: Can you recommend any specific thing i need to focus in given link so that i can ensure proper Authorization?

Comment: Thanks friend, your point was correct that i had some authorization issue. I deleted the project from Google cloud and recreated the project, changed my package name and followed instructions. thanks a lot :)